# I Want to split list into two lists right_order[] and reverse_order[], while comparing items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have `result` list where it has both ordered items like A, B and B, A combis or it can be 1,2 and 2,1 etc, if we found any reverse combis for  A, B or 1,2 or 3211, 3222 or anything then reversed combis should store in `target_list` and correct ordered combis should store in `source_list`. also if we don't find any reverse combis then add that to `source_list` but `target_list` must contain only reverse combis of items in `source_list` if we found.

Here is my code, I'm getting only for A, B combis can you tell how can I do dynamically like in place of A it can be anything and in place of B it can be anything that should satisfy the above-explained condition

```
result = [('A','B', 'IP1','GP1'), ('B', 'C', 'IP2','GP2'),('A', 'C', 'IP3','GP2'),('A','B', 'IP4','GP2'),('D', 'Z', 'IP5','GP2'),('B', 'A', 'IP6','GP2'), ('C','B','IP7','GP2'), ('C', 'A', 'IP8','GP2'),('C','B','IP9','GP2')]
a=[i for i,v in enumerate(result) if v[:2]==('B','A')]
Source_list,target_list=result[:a[0]],result[a[0]:]
print(Source_list)
print(target_list)
```

**output:**

> [('A', 'B', 'IP1', 'GP1'), ('B', 'C', 'IP2', 'GP2'), ('A', 'C', 'IP3', 'GP2'), ('A', 'B', 'IP4', 'GP2'), ('D', 'Z', 'IP5', 'GP2')] 
>   [('B', 'A', 'IP6', 'GP2'), ('C', 'B', 'IP7', 'GP2'), ('C', 'A', 'IP8', 'GP2'), ('C', 'B', 'IP9', 'GP2')]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understood what you what but you'll tell me...

```
def kamoulox(results):
    source_list = []
    target_list = []
    combis = set((result[0], result[1]) for result in results if result[0] <= result[1])
    for combi in combis:
        i = 0
        while i < len(results):
            if results[i][0:2] == combi:
                source_list.append(results.pop(i))
            elif results[i][0:2] == combi[::-1]:
                target_list.append(results.pop(i))
            else:
                i += 1
    return source_list, target_list

results = [
    ('32891', '32822', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-01', '10.88.158.81'),
    ('32822', '32891', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'),
    ('32822', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81'),
    ('32822', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'),
    ('32822', '32781', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'),
    ('32822', '32781', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81'),
    ('32822', '32781', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'),
    ('33033', '32891', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'),
    ('33033', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81'),
    ('33033', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'),
    ('33033', '32822', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-01', '10.88.158.81'),
    ('33033', '32781', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'),
    ('33033', '32781', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81'),
    ('33033', '32781', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'),
    ('32781', '32891', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'),
    ('32781', '32822', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-01', '10.88.158.81'),
    ('32781', '32822', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'),
    ('32781', '33033', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19')
]
source_list, target_list = kamoulox(results)

# source_list contains good ordered items (with or without reversed equivalent)
# target_list contains wrong ordered items with at least one equivalent into source_list
# results now contains wrong ordered items without good ordered equivalent
```

Comment: Sorry it is not generating correct output can you try with actual data of mine result 
[('32891', '32822', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-01', '10.88.158.81'), ('32822', '32891', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'), ('32822', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81'), ('32822', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'), ('32822', '32781', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'), ('32822', '32781', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81'), ('32822', '32781', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'), ('33033', '32891', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'),

Comment: ('33033', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81'), ('33033', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'), ('33033', '32822', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-01', '10.88.158.81'), ('33033', '32781', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'), ('33033', '32781', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81'), ('33033', '32781', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113'), ('32781', '32891', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'), ('32781', '32822', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-01', '10.88.158.81'), ('32781', '32822', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19'), ('32781', '33033', 'KSCYMOEC-MME-03', '10.148.9.19')]

Comment: Sorry I don't have space to post entire list so can you take list from two comments

Comment: Fixed. That should do what I understood of what you want.

Comment: This isn't fixed for huge data like atleast 7000 of tuples it is taking too much of time to loop for each and every 7000 combis and 7000 tuples, instead can i use itertools to make it fast? if yes how?